# mouse followed drawing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, drawing

I want to to make a shared drawing board in C#. This means that two people connected via a TCP connection can draw on this board. The idea (for now) is that people can click on the screen and draw. What do you think is the best method for this?
It's easy enough to draw a dot when the user clicks on a certain spot, but it gets a little more complicated when the user drags the mouse, where you need to draw a line between the last point and the current. Also that doesn't work so well, so I draw a dot where the line starts to improve things a bit, but it's not that good.

Lastly, I need to also send this over TCP, so I need to distinguish between the two. I hoped that I could just send points and have it draw it on the other side, but it seems it wouldn't work. Any ideas except also sending the type?

[drawing http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/9697/drawingw.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/9697/drawingw.png)

EDIT:
ok, I'm going with a IDrawingArgument interface that has Dispatch(myForm), and basically does double dispatch, so it solves the TCP problem (going to serialize/deserialize it).
Lines are still a bit bulky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One little tip... on your mousemove event. keep a flag that wont fire the event again until the last event that set the flag turns it off.  i.e.:

```
bool isDrawing = false;
public void myCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!isDrawing)
     {
         isDrawing = true;
         // Do drawing here
         isDrawing = false;
     }
}
```

This helped me a lot when doing drawing in a mousemove event.

Comment: I think that just might do it. It's basically a lock, I reckon?

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: The next time I added was a delay... Not letting the draw event fire unless its been at least 5 milliseconds since the last one fired.. or 3ms.. depending on your draw method.  This halps smooth out the drawing.

Comment: ^the next "thing" I adeed was a delay...^

Answer (score 0):

Dots:
(x,y),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)

Lines:
(x,y,x2,y2),(x3,y3,x4,y4)

Thus, the format is a list of tuples.  Tuples of size 4 are lines, of size 2 are points.  Note that if your system gets more complicated, you'll really regret not just doing something like:

Dots:
D(x,y),D(x2,y2),D(x3,y3)

Lines:
L(x,y,x2,y2),L(x3,y3,x4,y4)